# C# Collection not receiving data from SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I've been trying to populate a collection with data from a SQL Query, but it doesn't seem to be taking, and I'm not sure why.  I've confirmed that the connection string is good, and I have good reason to believe that the query itself is returning results, but the List collection doesn't want to populate.  The code compiles and runs without errors, but, like I said, no data in my List. :/  (note: the only data in the table are ints and varchars).
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
//create collection to dump SQL Query date into
List<String> creatureStats = new List<String>();

//Setup connection String to local DB
string connectionString = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.CreaturesConnectionString;

//Open connection to db and run SQL Query
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Creatures WHERE CreatureName = @creatureName;";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db))
    {
        //pass Creature name
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creatureName", creatureName);
        db.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
            while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(i))
                    {
                        if (reader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "int")
                            creatureStats.Add(creatureStats[i] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(i)));
                        else
                            creatureStats.Add(creatureStats[i] = reader.GetString(i));
                    }
                    else
                        creatureStats.Add(creatureStats[i] = string.Empty);
                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where specifically does it fail?  You have some `if` conditions in there, are they doing what you expect?

Comment: And you can write `creatureStats.Add(reader.GetString(i));` instead of `creatureStats.Add(creatureStats[i] = reader.GetString(i));`. Assigning your value to `creatureStats[i]` seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: The `for` loop should be inside the `while` loop, but even this way you should end up with something in the list, though not what you expect.

Comment: even with the flipped for / while - does the code return anything if you remove the where criteria?  i.e return data for all creatures.

Comment: @Crowcoder.  You're absolutely right, my for/while was definitely messed up.  I reversed through and starting seeing some forward progress!

Comment: @kmcnamee - thank you for calling my query into question.  It wasn't at all passing the where correctly.  I updated my query and it started processing results.  From there it was just a matter of refining it to what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your loops are mangled and incorrect.

```
while (reader.Read())
```

must be the outer loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount; i++)
```

must be the inner loop
because reader.read reads the next record of a whole record from the db.

so you need something like this instead

```
while (reader.Read()){
    for (int i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount; i++){
    }
}
```

now for the inner loop your code is very strange :

```
creatureStats.Add(creatureStats[i] = string.Empty);
creatureStats.Add(creatureStats[i] = reader.GetString(i));
creatureStats.Add(creatureStats[i] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(i)));
```

what are these statements supposed to do ? Even if this works the code is not clear and raises questions to whoever reads it. Split it up in 2 lines.
I didn't do anything with this yet because I cannot put myself in your shoes to know what was your intent with this statement. 
Looks to me like you change an array element, and meanwhile add it again. I don't understand the usefulness of this.

```
creatureStats.Add(string.Empty);
creatureStats.Add(reader.GetString(i));
creatureStats.Add(Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(i)));
```

might be your intent.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It's my first attempt at utilizing a local db, and I know, it's not wholly pretty.  ha ha.  I've updated the loop code as you've suggested, as well as rearranged the for/while.  This made a big difference, but ultimately the issue lied in how the variable was being passed to the query.  I've updated the query and we're pulling data! Hooray!

Answer (score -1):

After open connection:

```
db.Open();
```

you must write this:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```